# Regex remove/replace ending of URLs

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to remove/replace ending of URLs with regex in notepad++

The Urls looks like this but with different numbers.

```
-p-936486.html
-p-936488.html
-p-934486.html
```

i want to remove -p-936486 and keep .html in the Urls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search

```
-p-\d+\.html$
```

Replace

```
.html
```

Assuming that each URL is one line. If not, remove `$` to match the expression anywhere and not only at the end of a line

Comment: thanks solved the problem for me without $ as you mentioned :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have notepad++, but assuming the regexp evaluator there is similar  to Komodoedit, here's ten regexp to match the patter of "-p-{any number of digits) - use that, and replace with a blank string

-p-[0-9]+

Answer (score 1):

In Notepad++ to replace, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to open the Replace menu, check the "Regular expression" button, and use

Find: \-p\-\d{6}(\.html)

Replace: \1